# Ternary using pass keyword python

Tags: python, conditional-statements, ternary

I have a working conditional statement:

```
if True:
    pass
else:
    continue
```

that I would like to turn it into a ternary expression:

```
pass if True else continue
```

However, Python does not allow this. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Comment: Your example makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Point 1**: Are your sure your condition is right? Because `if True` will always be `True` and code will never go to `else` block.

**Point 2**: `pass` and `continue` are not expressions or values, but a action instead You can not use these is one line. Instead if you use, `3 if x else 4` <-- it will work

Comment: I have a boolean is_string instead of True. So it's if is_string->pass, else-> continue

Answer (score 3):

`pass` and `continue` are a statements, and cannot be used within ternary operator, since the operator expects expressions, not statements. Statements don't evaluate to values in Python.

Nevertheless, you can still shorten the condition you brought like this:

```
if False: continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Ternary expression are used to compute values; neither `pass` nor `continue` are values.